# How to integrate and use github in atom

Tags: repository, github

Unfortunately github does not have an official client for Linux .
Therefore I want to know if there is a way to integrate github to atom (Their text editor) and manage the github repos directly through atom. 
Is there a plugin or is it already integrated??
I'm **new** to atom (and github) so please explain completely!

Comment: Perhaps this documentation page will be helpful: https://atom.io/docs/v0.194.0/using-atom-version-control-in-atom

Comment: There is a more recent blog entry, if you prefer http://blog.atom.io/2014/03/13/git-integration.html

Comment: U&L is not a learning platform, specifically _I am new to XYZ, so please explain completely_ does not fit here.

Answer (score 1):

There are official packages with Git support, but nothing that would specifically bind your editor to GitHub's services.

If you'd like to be up-to-date, querying Atom packages will give you readily available access to current Git and GitHub integrations: https://atom.io/packages/search?q=git and https://atom.io/packages/search?q=github respectively.

If you feel like there's something missing, then you can think about developing your own plugin and sharing it with the community. These resources might be helpful:

- [GitHub's official API](https://developer.github.com/v3/)
- [GitHub's Developer program](https://developer.github.com/program/) might help you get additional programmatic access to their services or membership beefits
- [Atom Documentation](https://atom.io/docs)